# Can you download the XNA Connect app in US so I can deploy to Xbox 360?

Tags: xna, xbox360, pc

I've got an XNA Creators Club trial membership via DreamSpark, but I cannot download the [XNA Game Studio Connect](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/XNA-Game-Studio-Connect/00000000-0000-400c-80af-e002584e07d1) app due to a bug in the site. Users from Finland and US experienced this [before](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/12850.aspx) and MS fixed something in the Marketplace configuration that enabled them to download this. You need this app to deploy apps to Xbox 360 during development.

Can someone with a Creators Club account please download this app for me and upload it [someplace](http://www.mediafire.com/)?

I'm legal since my account on App Hub shows Registered, Student, and Premium Member.

[image: Premium Member pic]

Comment: That app needs to be downloaded on the Xbox itself, not the PC, right? So not sure how one would go around to do that "for you"...

Comment: Well I assumed they'd give you a installer file (on the PC, on the LIVE marketplace site) which you could just send over to me!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only see a button to download to my Xbox 360. When I clicked it, it said it was added to my "queue", and I guess it will magically show up on my Xbox? But there is nothing I saw to download...

Here is a screenshot of the page I see: (notice the "Download to Xbox 360" button in the bottom right)

[image: XNA Game Studio Connect]

---

Edit: I found the queue. And it is as I suspected. My Xbox hasn't recognized the download yet, but I think I already have the XNA Game Studio Connect app on my Xbox, so I'm not sure if it will ever (re-)download.
[image: Xbox Download Queue]

Comment: Can you find the "queue" somewhere and try to download it someplace?

Comment: @Edwardian - Found it. See edit. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

According to [the XNA team's blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/xna/xblig-4-0-submission-opens-on-app-hub-this-friday) today (Fri Nov 5) the connect application will be updated to accept XNA4.0 deployments. I'm guessing you are seeing transients related to the upgrade process.

If I were you I would try again later today, once the new connect app has been fielded in all markets.